# Some way to back up and delete an RDS instance, then restore it later?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Sometimes I need to do a lot of testing using Amazon RDS MariaDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server instances. (This is specifically testing our product with RDS so I can't use Docker.) Other times, months may go by without my needing any of those instances. But they took a long time to set up and configure so I don't want to delete them.

Is there some way to back them up, download the backup, delete the instance, and then, when I need it again a few months later, create a new instance and restore the backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: Amazon RDS Snapshots**

You can create an **Amazon RDS Snapshot**, which contains a copy of the database. You can later create a new database from the Snapshot.

Backup storage is billed at `$0.095 per GiB-month`. This is slightly cheaper than the cost of active database storage, which is billed at `$0.115 per GB-month`.

After creating the Snapshot, you can terminate the database so that the hourly cost is not charged.

You could easily create scripts to:

- Snapshot a database and then terminate it
- Create a new database from a Snapshot

It is *not* possible to download Amazon RDS Snapshots.

**Option 2: Export to Amazon S3**

Amazon RDS can export data to Amazon S3 for MySQL, MariaDB and PostgreSQL databases. It is also possible to create a new RDS database from these imports, but **only for MySQL**.

See: [Restoring a backup into a MySQL DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html)

**Option 3: Export via traditional methods**

This option involves using traditional methods for exporting data and then importing it again. This varies by database engine.

Some tips are given on: [Import Data Into an Amazon RDS DB Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-import-data/)

**Bottom Line**

Use Amazon RDS Snapshots. You'll save time and sanity in exchange for the snapshot storage cost.

Comment: Thanks. Making it impossible to download snapshots is of a piece with starting a stopped database after a week. But that should be pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon restoring RDS instances from snapshots is the way to go: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html